# sql server select performance guid vs string

Tags: sql-server

**This is not about PKs!**

I wonder which will be faster on select:

```
select * from stuff where someguidcol = '83ce47d2-ac4c-488a-863c-c5f31e8f87aa'
```

or this one

```
select * from stuff where somestrcol = 'DS3DvDVIPEG1X8Ui7U84DA'
```

*somestrcol datatype will be char(22)*

*Non-clustered indexes will be applied, probably...*

Comment: this reminds me of something my company did...

Comment: `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is a 16-byte GUID.  That means an index page can hold more of them than the number of 22 character strings that will fit.  On that basis GUIDs should have a small performance advantage.  Maintainability is probably a more important issue when designing a database.